# Read large numpy-array as czi-file in python

Tags: python, numpy, bioinformatics, array-broadcasting

I have the following snippet:

```
from aicspylibczi import CziFile
from pathlib import Path

pth = Path('/Volumes/USB/20x_HE.czi')
czi = CziFile(pth)

image, shp = czi.read_image(C=0, M=0)   # very slow
```

The parameters C und M are there to slice the big array in to little numpy pieces.

The File is 3,4GB big and it is taking to long(with 8GB RAM Macbook) so I abort it always.

I think thats not okay because I want to have the first slice of the array, not the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try slideio python package (http://slideio.com). It makes use of internal image pyramids. You can read the image partially with high resolution or the whole image with low resolution.
The code below rescales the image so that the width of the delivered raster will be 500 pixels (the height is computed to keep the image size ratio).

```
import slideio
slide = slideio.open_slidei(file_path="/data/a.czi",driver_id="CZI")
scene = slide.get_scene(0)
block = scene.read_block(size=(500,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

By slice do you mean the first slice of a z-stack? The package you are using, `aicspylibczi`, allows you to specify a z coordinate e.g. to read the first z-slice:

```
image, shp = czi.read_image(C=0, M=0, Z=0)
```